# The mechanism of annotations in Symfony - how does it all work?

Tags: php, symfony

I have started to learn Symfony (4.1) and I have a question about annotations.

As far as I know, annotation are just comments in terms of php and they are not a part of the language itself. However they are rather powerful thing in Symfony.

I want to know, how it all works.

- Is there a code preprocessor which parses the source files dynamically and creates new php entities?
- But if it's so, how does it affect the performance of an application?
- Why should I use special namespaces for certain annotations?

Put simply, I would like to know how do annotations in Symfony work, the mechanism of this feature.

Comment: I think that's an interesting question I personally don't know the answer to but I do know know that there are different types of annotations. For example, the doctrine ORM can use annotations to specify how an entity should map to a table in the db while Symfony validations can use assert annotations to enforce validation rules on entity properties at the model level. Also interesting to note that annotations are optional and you could, at least in Symfony 3, achieve the same via complimenting XML files, for example but annotations certainly seems to be more popular these days.

Comment: My point or rather addition to the question would be - do these libraries process annotations differently or is there a central, shared package they all use under the hood?

Comment: Whoever googles this up, things may be changing with [introduction of PHP8 attributes](http://graphqlite.thecodingmachine.io/docs/doctrine-annotations-attributes)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, indeed, annotations are not part of the language itself. But they're also not the part of Symfony framework.

Annotations are usually handled by [`doctrine/annotations`](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-annotations/en/1.6/index.html) package (most common). It utilizes reflection to read and parse these comments and transform them into annotation objects ([every annotation has an annotation class](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-annotations/en/1.6/index.html#create-an-annotation-class) which it represents). 
Then, its up to the library to make use of generated objects representing these annotations.

So to answer first question - yes, there is a preprocessor. But it doesn't "create new php entities", because its the job for the library that uses those annotations (e.g. Symfony framework or Doctrine ORM).

How it affects the performance, depends on the library that uses them. If they would be parsed on every request, that would indeed affect performance. So e.g. Symfony and Doctrine ORM cache this data or create proxy classes etc.

So the answer to second question is - it might if used incorrectly, but it usually is not (in production environment) as they are simply not parsed every time.

The last question doesn't really relates to annotations. Since annotations are really classes, the reason for namespacing them is also the same. To avoid conflicts between libraries and for sake of readability.

Comment: So I guess then that under the hood `doctrine/annotations` will use `ReflectionProperty::getDocComment` and co to access the information in the comments?

Comment: @Bananaapple yes, it does use `getDocComment`, but not only of `ReflectionProperty` class, but also `ReflectionMethod` and `ReflectionClass`, since annotations can be assigned to  classes and methods too.